# Method requires self argument

Tags: python, class, oop, canvas, tkinter

I have this code right here, it's about a GUI app with Tkinter, pretty simple, but there is one error that I can't solve without breaking the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Sistema:

    def __init__(self, g1 = 0, g2 = 0, g3 = 0, g4 = 0, media = 6):
        self.g1 = g1
        self.g2 = g2
        self.g3 = g3
        self.g4 = g4
        self.media = media
        resultCalc = (self.g1 + self.g2 + self.g3 + self.g4) / 4
        self.resultCalc = resultCalc


        Label_reply['text'] = Sistema.__str__()
    def __str__(self):

        if self.resultCalc < self.media:
            return "Você não passou de ano! ╰（‵□′）╯"
        elif self.resultCalc > self.media:
            return "Você passou de ano!(～￣▽￣)～"
        elif self.resultCalc == self.media:
            return "Você passou de ano! Essa foi por pouco (。_。)"
        else:
            return "Erro fatal (╬▔皿▔)╯"


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg = "#159BA0", height = 500, width = 500)
canvas.pack()

Label1 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Digite sua nota:")
Label1.place(x = 10,y = 10)
Entry1 = tk.Entry(canvas)
Entry1.place(x = 100,y = 10)

Label2 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Digite sua nota:")
Label2.place(x = 10,y = 50)
Entry2 = tk.Entry(canvas)
Entry2.place(x = 100,y = 50)

Label3 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Digite sua nota:")
Label3.place(x = 10, y = 90)
Entry3 = tk.Entry(canvas)
Entry3.place(x = 100, y = 90)

Label4 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Digite sua nota:" )
Label4.place(x = 10, y = 130)
Entry4 = tk.Entry(canvas)
Entry4.place(x = 100, y = 130)

Label5 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Média mínima: ")
Label5.place(x=10, y = 170)
Entry5 = tk.Entry(canvas)
Entry5.place(x=100, y = 170)

Button1 = tk.Button(canvas, text = "Enviar",
command = lambda : Sistema(float(Entry1.get()), float(Entry2.get()), float(Entry3.get()), float(Entry4.get()), 
float(Entry5.get())))
Button1.place(x = 10, y = 210)

Label_reply = tk.Label(canvas)
Label_reply.place(x = 10, y = 240)

root.mainloop()
```

But, when I run it, it raises this exception:

```
TypeError: __str__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

The error is at the 15 line.
I know what it means and why it happens, but I can't find a way to solve it without ruining the code, can someone help me?

Comment: Replace `Sistema.__str__()` with `str(self)` which will in turn call `__str__`

Comment: i tried to run your code by passing self to __str()__  such as Label_reply['text'] = Sistema.__str__(self) ,i think it works.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to move the code for the button command to a function. Embedded a lot of code in a lambda makes the code hard to read and hard to debug.

Comment: Hey Luka, I used you tip, and It worked, as you said, the code is not great, lol, but it worked, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
Label_reply['text'] = Sistema.__str__()
```

You are calling the `__str__` method on the *class* rather than on an *instance* of the class. That is why it is asking for the `self` parameter.

I assume you want to call the `__str__` method of the current object, which you can do by calling `str(self)`:

```
Label_reply['text'] = str(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line:

```
      Label_reply['text'] = Sistema.__str__()
```

This is an incorrect call to the `__str__` function (it would need to be something more like `str(self)`), and it serves no purpose since there is no `Label_reply` within this scope anyway.

Instead, put the logic of updating `Label_reply` inside your `command` function:

```
Label_reply = tk.Label(canvas)
Label_reply.place(x = 10, y = 240)
def command():
    s = Sistema(
        float(Entry1.get()), 
        float(Entry2.get()), 
        float(Entry3.get()), 
        float(Entry4.get()), 
        float(Entry5.get())
    )
    Label_reply['text'] = str(s)
    return s
```

Comment: It serves a purpose, it is at the bottom of the script. The code is not great, but I tested it and it works.

Comment: Updated answer -- you should put that logic inside your `command` instead of in the `Sistema` constructor.  Otherwise your constructor will raise any time there doesn't happen to be a `Label_reply` in the calling scope.